# Symfony bundle namespacing

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I set a Bundle which is called Mine:

```
src/Mine/DemoBundle/Controller        
src/Mine/DemoBundle/Entity/user/User.php
```

my routing is:

```
 defaults: { _controller: MineDemo:User:create }
```

UserController.php starts like this:

```
namespace Mine\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Mine\DemoBundle\Entity\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function createAction()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setName('Jonathan H. Wage');

        $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        // ...
    }
```

and User.php is:

```
namespace Mine\DemoBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * Mine\DemoBundle\Entity\User\User
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string $name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mine\DemoBundle\Entity\User' not found
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\src\Mine\DemoBundle\Controller\UserController.php on line 12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace on your class should be

```
namespace Mine\DemoBundle\Entity;
```

instead of

```
namespace Mine\DemoBundle\Entity\User;
```